# SwiftUI List Separator within NavigationView Problem

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationview

I'm not sure if this is well-known-issue or not but it is very odd. The problem can be reproduced with Apple's example code [navigationBarItems(leading:trailing:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/navigationbaritems(leading:trailing:)) As you can see, list separators have extra leading space that look like they are indented for some reason.

[image]

Here is actual code:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Text("Chocolate")
                Text("Vanilla")
                Text("Strawberry")
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Today‘s Flavors"))
            .navigationBarItems(leading:
                HStack {
                    Button("Hours") {
                        print("Hours tapped!")
                    }
                }, trailing:
                HStack {
                    Button("Favorites") {
                        print("Favorites tapped!")
                    }

                    Button("Specials") {
                        print("Specials tapped!")
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

I test above code with Playground, iPhone 13/15.3.1 they are the same.
I did messing around the code and found that applying .navigationBarTitle(), .navigationBarItems() to List causes the problem. They must apply to each List item. Very odd though. This means almost all List sample code that wrapping with NavigationView are WRONG. Here is a fix I found.

[image]

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ContentView: View {
    let contents = ["Chocolate", "Vanilla", "Strawberry"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach (contents, id: \.self) { content in
                    Text(content)
                        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Today‘s Flavors"))
                        .navigationBarItems(leading:
                            HStack {
                                Button("Hours") {
                                    print("Hours tapped!")
                                }
                            }, trailing:
                            HStack {
                                Button("Favorites") {
                                    print("Favorites tapped!")
                                }

                                Button("Specials") {
                                    print("Specials tapped!")
                                }
                            }
                        )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

Although I'm not sure if I can call this is a bug but definitely either document or implementation is wrong. Could anyone explain this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please, do not post images of code. Post the actual code, formatted, in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`navigationBarItems` will be deprecated in the future so you should use `toolbar` instead

```
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
        Button("Hours") { }
    }
}
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
        HStack {
            Button("Favorites") { }
            Button("Specials") { }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to keep using `navigationBarItems`, there is a better work around by using other `ListStyle`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Text("Chocolate")
                Text("Vanilla")
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Today‘s Flavors"))
            .navigationBarItems(
                leading: Button("Hours") { }
            )
            .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
        }
    }
}
```

do not apply `navigationBarTitle` on every row for a work around, it's bad

Comment: Man, adding . listStyle(PlainListStyle()) solved the problem. I was under impression that the default style is PlainListStyle so no need to set style explicitly, never tried that. Thanks!

Comment: @J.K you can also use `.list(.plain)` instead of `PlainListStyle()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply **ANY** (whatever you want) style to the List and then everything will be ok.